# Access combobox store 1 value, display another

Tags: ms-access, vba, combobox

I'm have a query that returns the following columns:

Code
LastName
FirstName

I have a combobox where all of this info is displayed in the dropdown.  But when I select a row, all I see in the combobox is the Code (its an employee number).  What I'd like to do is display:

> "[Code] - [LastName], [FirstName]"

as the selected item when a value is selected, and still store just the [Code] in the combobox's .Value property.

How is this done?  I'm used to C#.NET where a dropdown has 2 properties (displayValue and selectedValue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** In this method you won't be able to have the formatting (dash or comma):

Set the column count to 3.
Set the Bound column to 1 (it's one-based, even though the .Column property is zero-based).
Adjust column widths to a pleasing arrangement.
Set RowSourceType to "Table/Query".
Set RowSource to your query.
Do *not* set a Control Source (leave blank--this leaves the .Value unbound from underlying data).

You can do all the above in Design View.

**2.** This method is more work, but gets exactly what you asked for:

In Design View:
Set column count to 2.
Set Bound Column to 1,
SetColumn Widths to `0";2"` (accepts inches or cm, and if you just enter undecorated numbers will read them as inches (or as set in Options(?))).
Set RowSourceType to "Value List".
Do *not* set a Control Source (leave blank--this leaves the .Value unbound from underlying data).

Write this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

'declare variables & open query as recordset--left as exercise

    With Combo1
        .Clear
        Do Until rs.EOF
            .AddItem rs.Code & ";" & rs!Code & " - " & rs!LastName & ", " & rs!FirstName
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    'close rs & clean up--another exercise

End Sub
```

The semicolon between the `rs!Code` instances in the string concatenation is what points them into the appropriate columns.

Comment: I've edited my answer, so you can remove the reference to my old answer.  I like your solution the best.

Answer (score 1):

In the BeforeUpdate event (there might be a better one, that's just what I tested on), set the .Text property to the string you want.

```
Me.ComboBox1.Text = [Code] & " - " & [LastName] & ", " & [FirstName]
```

Note that you may have to play with the string construction.

Comment: I actually have these settings already, and I'm not seeing what I want.  Perhaps I should clarify: I want the selected item to have [code] - LastName, FirstName.  I already have it in the dropdown.

Comment: @MAW74656, ok, edited something, gotta run now, so I wasn't able to fully test things out (I'd probably need more detail of your exact setup also).

Comment: Do I have to use a DLookup to get each field, or is there an easier way?

Comment: @MAW74656, I'm not sure, it depends on how the table was queried, but I think the answer you accepted is the best one, so it looks like you'll be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The following might help to add information to the combo box with 3 columns. Note that the column widths at the bottom is used to "hide" the first column

```
For x = 1 To 10
    ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 3
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Code"                          ' Column 1 data
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "LastName"    ' Column 2 data
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "FirstName"   ' Column 3 data
        'etc.
    End With
    ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = "0cm;2.5cm;2.0cm"
Next
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:

```
DisplayString = code & " - " & Lastname & ", " & Firstname
ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2
With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Code"                             ' Column 1 data
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = DisplayString    ' Column 2 data
End With

ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = "0cm;4.5cm;"
```

Comment: I already have the combobox databound to a query.  Is the only way to change the display to add each item programmatically?  I'm not seeing how this helps.

Comment: This is not an Access way of working with combo boxes -- the usual approach is to populate them with a SQL statement using data from a table.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working the way I want now.  Here's what I did:

-Did the concat in the sql, so the query returns columns [Code] and [DisplayName].
-Bound = 1, Columns = 2, Column Widths = 0:1"

Now the display value is what I specified in my SQL and the selected value (tested and confirmed) is just the code.

Thanks for the help, I'm not well versed in Access vba.

Comment: The above is not an answer -- you should either edit your original question to include it or add it to the question as a comment.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton -I disagree.  The above explains what was done to solve the problem.  That is an answer.  But I didn't select it as THE answer because @RolandTumble had a very complete explanation of the issue.  I don't see the problem here.